# Using pytest, is it possible for a unit test to know that it is being run with code coverage monitoring on?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, coverage.py

I am currently developing some tests using python py.test / unittest that, via subprocess, invoke another python application (so that I can exercise the command line options, and confirm that the tool is installed correctly).

I would like to be able to run the tests in such a way that I can get a view of the code coverage metrics (using coverage.py) for the target application using pytest_cov. By default this does not work as the code coverage instrumentation does not apply to code invoked with subprocess.

Code Coverage of the code does work if I update the tests to directly invoke the entry class for the target application (rather than running via the command line).

Ideally I want to have a single set of code which can be run in two ways:

1. If code coverage monitoring is not enabled then use command line
2. Otherwise execute the main class of the target application.

Which leads to my question(s):

- Is it possible for a python unit test to determine if it is being run with code coverage enabled?
- Otherwise: is there any easy way to pass a command line flag from the pytest invocation that can be used to set the mode within the code.

Comment: You could check if `--with-cov` was passed via command line or config.

Answer (score 0):

Coverage.py has a facility to automatically measure coverage in sub-processes that are spawned: http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Coverage sets three environment flags when running tests: `COV_CORE_SOURCE`, `COV_CORE_CONFIG` and `COV_CORE_DATAFILE`.

So you can use a simple if-statement to verify whether the current test is being run with coverage enabled:

```
import os

if "COV_CORE_SOURCE" in os.environ:
    # do what yo need to do when Coverage is enabled
```